# change \thepage only for pagination not for references

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, page-numbering

I changed the font size of the pagination with 
     `\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\footnotesize\arabic{page}}}` 
and it worked great, but it also changed the font size  for the references on this pages (`\pageref`) in the text itself. Is there a way to prevent this?

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{article}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\footnotesize\arabic{page}}}
\begin{document}
It is shown in the equation \pageref{A}.
\begin{equation}
    A = B
    \label{A}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

edit:
Solution with fancyhdr:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%For headers/footers
\pagestyle{fancy} %%For fancy headers

\begin{document}
\fancyhf{} %clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{{\footnotesize\thepage}} %set fontsize for pagination in footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %remove footer rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove header rule
It is shown in the equation \pageref{A}.
    \begin{equation}
        A = B
        \label{A}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex! Please [provide a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Welcome, use `\footnotesize\thepage` when defining the header/footer. Do'nt redfine the page output in general.

Comment: But then I have to change the template, where the pagination is defined right?

Comment: This question is unclear, it is an XY-problem. The question should have been *How can i get the page number in the header/footer smaller?*. XY-problems cannot be solved by answering the posted question x but by identifying the real question Y. An answer to Y hardly can be the answer to X. I therefor vote to close this question as unclear.

Comment: @datafridge, you can answer to own question. In your question it will not be seen well.

Comment: @datafridge Posting your solution as an answer will also have the advantage, that people can upvote it, if they like it.

Comment: @samcarter thank you, I add the solution also as an answer

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

[image: datafridgeHeaderFooter]
<sub>The other 1 in the footer is just for comparison. It is normal sized.</sub>

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{article}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
It is shown in the equation \pageref{A}.
\begin{equation}
    A = B
    \label{A}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own page style (called `mystyle` in the example below):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@mystyle{% definition of page style "mystyle"
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\footnotesize\hfil\thepage\hfil}
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{mystyle} % use of page style "mystyle"

\begin{document}
It is shown in the equation \pageref{A}.
\begin{equation}
  A = B
  \label{A}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A caveat: You may want to point out explicitly that this method really only works with the `article` document class. It will fail for document classes such as `report` and `book`; for these document classes, it will be necessary to modify the `headings` and/or `myheadings` page styles as well as the `plain` page style, which is used by default on pages that contain chapter headers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me with fancyhdr:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%For headers/footers
\pagestyle{fancy} %%For fancy headers

\begin{document}
\fancyhf{} %clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{{\footnotesize\thepage}} %set fontsize for pagination in footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %remove footer rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove header rule
It is shown in the equation \pageref{A}.
    \begin{equation}
        A = B
        \label{A}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```